# How to create Summary and Aggregate reports from a .jtl file?

Tags: jmeter

I am running a JMeter Performance test in non-GUI mode. I get the results in .jtl file. Is there a quick and easy way to produce Summary and Aggregate reports from this file?

Answer (score 26):

If you're using jmeter 3.2, here are the following steps.

1. Open the JMeter GUI
2. Right click on Test Plan, Go to Add, then Listener and then click on Aggregate Report.
3. Where it say's Filename, either input the path of where your jtl file is located or click browse & find it.
4. Click the Save Table Data button below

Answer (score 13):

Yes. You can import/open the .jtl file in JMeter GUI.

Please follow these steps -

1. Open JMeter GUI.
2. Open Summary and Aggregrate Report tab.
3. Browse the .jtl to read the results from the file.

Comment: I don't see any tabs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is an easy way to do this. You can reopen JMeter .jtl file in any Jmeter Listener however you need to make sure that you have saved the results from JMeter in an xml format.
To do this in Non-gui mode, edit your jmeter.properties file and set:
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml

Comment: Nice! Not a very intuitive way of doing it, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

- right click on "Test Plan"
- select "add" > "Listener"

you should see a number of options, all of which take your jtl file as input and display it in various forms.

Answer (score 0):

A jtl file is basically a csv. You could simply copy paste its contents into an excel, then use data filters or pivot tables to create your summary/aggregate.